# What's the difference between WLED and RGBLED displays?

Tags: display, lcd

On Dell's website, it lists displays as being "WLED" or "RGBLED". What is the difference between these two types of displays?

Comment: WLED: ugly colors. RGBLED: flashy colors. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, I'll take a stab at the RGB question. The backlight of the screen used to be cold cathode type bulbs. Think super thin flourescents. The problem is that they were power hungry. The next generation used a white light LED to save on power. The problem is that there is no such animal as a white LED. The LED is actually a yellow LED with a blue coat. Sometimes that creates a slight shift in color. Slight yellow or yellow green tones are common. You display may show this shift with slightly off color images.

RGB uses pure color Red/Green/Blue LED's. When you focus them together, they create a true white light and this focused through the display should create brighter, truer colors.

Comment: See http://ledtele.co.uk/whatisledtv.html

Comment: It's a blue led with a yellow phospor. Blue is the higher energy light type, and can be converted to the lower energy yellow light, not the other way around.

Comment: RGB is still no true white. It is still producing a peaked spectrum instead of the continuous daylight spectrum. White leds have 2 peaks, a yellow and a blue one, the rgb leds produce a 3 peaked spectrum. A normal (5500K temperature) light bulb still makes the best real white light.

Comment: The energy saving on current LED types is still questionable. Most LED monitors have a lower light output, more like 300cd/m2 instead of 400-500 in most modern CCFL screens, and thus having the max output as main reason for energy saving.

Comment: Mixing red, green, and blue together does not really produce white light, it only produces a light that looks white to human beings (not necessarily to other animals) because our eyes only have receptors for these three colors and if all three receptors are equally lit, we "see" white, as real white light would also do that with our receptors, yet this is basically just an illusion for our eyes.

Answer (score 11):

White LED's are actually blue leds with a yellow phosphor, and thus creating an white impression. This technique allows a colour gamut slightly wider than sRGB, but not very "colourfull".
RGB leds consist of 3 individual colour leds, red, green and blue. These allow an enourmous colour gamut that covers most standards like AdobeRGB and NTSC. Panels with RGB LED's are much more expensive, as they need much more calibration logic. It is very hard to tame extreme gamut for say sRGB use, and the ballance of the colours is constantly monitored. RGB LED displays are doing twice the price of WLED's with ease.

Answer (score 2):

WLED or RGBLED Displays are misnomers, the pixels are not LEDs but LCDs. So to be correct, we should have (if abbreviation must be used) LED b-l LCD Displays where b-l stands for back-light. Soon we should have 'true' LED Displays. What do you think?

Comment: OLED displays are already here, although it is a very small part of the market so far.  One of my closest friends is a scientist who has been researching the problems with the blue component for the last decade, at DuPont.

Comment: They are no misnomers, as these terms only talk about the backlit and the backlit are true LEDs, either those that emit white light (through a trick but that doesn't matter) or those that mix red, green, and blue light together to give the impression of white light. Nobody every claimed that these terms talk about the pixels on screen.