# How to find out if the screen is WLED or RGBLED on Dell Studio XPS 16?

Tags: lcd, display, led, dell-xps, backlight

I just ordered the Dell Studio XPS 16 with i7 and 16" RGBLED screen. This upgrade from WLED LCD to RGBLED LCD charged me more $$. But now when I view the order online, it lists this part as "320-8335 Premium FHD WLED Display, Obsidian Black, 2.0 MP Webcam". When called Dell, the rep says this part is RGBLED screen and the "premium" is for RGBLED. I want to make sure they are shipping me the RGBLED screen and not the WLED.

Is there any way to verify this after I receive (either from Device Manager or BIOS or somewhere in system settings)? Also, is there any published specifications / criteria that we can run (some third party software) on this monitor which can tell if this is WLED or RGBLED?

Comment: In case any readers were, like me, wondering what the difference is between WLED and RGBLED, there are answers here: http://superuser.com/questions/61141/whats-the-difference-between-wled-and-rgbled-displays
( What’s the difference between WLED and RGBLED displays? )

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is ages old, but thought I'd add my two cents in case anyone else stumbles across the question.

I've got an RGBLED on a Dell Studio XPS, probably the same or similar to the OP.  I found that if I look at the screen with polarised sunglasses on (the ones that block glare off water - good for fishing), then the screen looks very pink or green, depending on the angle I hold my head.  For normal monitors I don't get any colour shift but the screen looks completely black if I tilt my head 90 degrees.

Hope that's of interest to someone!

Answer (score 0):

I also ordered the same notebook with the upgrade RGBLED display, and it also said Premium HD WLED Display in the final parts manifest. And by the way, these displays are AWESOME. The support person is correct -- he should get credit for the higher rating :)

Comment: But are you sure this "Premium FHD WLED" is not really a WLED and is a RGBLED? Some of my friends are confused about this too; not sure how to verify if Dell is sending the correct display. The "WLED" word in the item description makes me nervous.

Comment: I am working on the RGBLED model in question as we speak. The sheer depth of color actually blows away my desktop monitor, a 24" panel with 92% color gamut. How much more evidence do you need??

Comment: Well, I really appreciate your help. But I am looking for some concrete evidence against which I can verify the screen I receive. Some software tool or by any means as such. I have never seen either WLED or RGBLED. So if they put any of them in front of me, I will feel much difference as compared to older screens. So unlike you I cannot be sure that I received RGBLED. As we are paying big bucks for these high-tech things, I want to make sure I have what I paid for. Do you think there is any way by which I can make sure the one I receive is really RGBLED?

Comment: The only way to get more 'concrete' than someone's firsthand experience is to go out and buy a colorimeter to test it yourself when you receive it: http://www.xrite.com/product_overview.aspx?ID=788

Anandtech did a review of the same notebook with the RGBLED (http://www.anandtech.com/mobile/showdoc.aspx?i=3540) - you can compare your results with theirs.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Josh. Today again I called Dell asking if this "Premium WLED" is RGBLED (this time I called their tech support, not order support) and she told me it looks different. She told me she will give me a call back once she finds out the difference and why it says "WLED". Probably the "Standard" WLED display has 1600x900 resolution and "Premium" WLED display has 1920x1080 (same as RGBLED).

Answer (score 0):

If you check their website now, only the RGB LED is 16", the WLED is 15.6".

Comment: Check your resolution: 1920x1080 is RGBLED, 1600x900 is WLED

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays WLED 15.6" is also available in 1920 x 1080 resolution.

Months ago, you could buy 16" or 15.6" in 720p, now both 16" and 15.6" are available in 1080p

Answer (score 0):

Go to Device manager - Monitors - Properties - Details tab - Scroll to Hardware Ids under property and check if it is SEC5448. RGBs come with this Id.