# Whats the difference between WLED and LED in displays?

Tags: display, terminology, led

I want to buy a laptop which have LED backlit display but there are other laptops better than that with WLED backlit display having same price tag. Can anyone explain me what's the difference between these two displays?

And my question ain't same as "What is difference between WLED and RGBLED?"

I asked the difference between WLED AND LED. There are many other laptop having WLED display and some show that there laptop got LED display. For this confusion I have asked this question.

Don't relate it with other questions.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between WLED and RGBLED displays?](http://superuser.com/questions/61141/whats-the-difference-between-wled-and-rgbled-displays)

Comment: @DavidPostill - actually not.  LED != RGBLED - which is something different to what the OP has asked - although it is certainly related.

Comment: I read that post before but didn't got rid of my confusion can you answer my real question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Marketing](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Hardware-and-Upgrade-Questions/diagonal-hd-led-backlit-vs-hd-Wled/td-p/4145620) - there is no difference.

LED = Light Emitting Diode - in case of screens its white.
WLED = White Light emitting diode.

Comment: Note that LED != LCD though.  If a screen does not say LED or similar, it is probably not using LED lighting, which means more power usage and less even color distribution because older LCD's will use CCFL lighting which is at top and bottom.

Comment: OK thnx alot mate for replying :)